# Backend PHP that performs a Request to an API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an API for User Login, but while doing the AJAX in the front end, Im exposing sensitive parameters like; merchant id, etc. What I want to know is if I can host a PHP script which my Front End can pass parameters to, then for that PHP script to do the AJAX and include the sensitive parameters so users wont see them.

This is my front end AJAX, I want to hide these parameters in the PHP:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.com/api',
            type: "POST",

            data: ({
                'api_username': 'abc123', //keep this hidden.
                'api_password': 'password', // keep this hidden.
                'MODULE': 'Customer',
                'FILTER[email]': $('#email').val(),
                'FILTER[password]': $('#password').val(),
                'COMMAND': 'validate',
                'jsonResponse' : 'true',
                'click': 'Display'
            })
```

Comment: PHP can't do `AJAX`, you should google what `AJAX` actually is. But PHP can make a request to the API just fine.

Comment: Oh I see Thanks. How do I actually host the PHP script that will perform what I want, is it possible to not even have a DB for what Im trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can cheat, by doing a MD5($merchantID); and it will hash it for you...

Comment: @Levi, the merchantID is fixed and static. So even if I convert it to MD5, I still have to write a function that converts the static value, and the value will still be exposed in the front end.

Comment: Structure your login to only accept the username/password values then assign your sessions behind everything then on your pages do a echo session? @Pickles

Comment: @Levi, can you elaborate on this? What I want to achieve is to completely hide the parameters  from any of my JS files and my network activity.

Comment: When you're passing PHP variables they're only serverside.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually read your question a little slower.. lol normally just skim. First off you shouldnt be passing your 'login' information via ajax. AJAX is ment to do LIVE posts/queries on your sql table without refreshing or changing pages.

Comment: Oh ok, so what do you suggest for completely hiding the parameters from the front end? PHP API request from backend is the first thing I thought of.

Comment: You want to first validate that the user exists by forcing them to login. I am not sure if you're maybe using the wrong lingo, but maybe you're referring to having the user simply login to validate that they're legitimate? If so, read up on this page. http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html

Comment: OK so no AJAX? how do I go about posting to the API? given my situation?

Comment: And the most important thing I can tell you right now -- DO NOT USE MYSQL_ or mysqli_. Use PDO its secure, and you will not be told every single time you have a question that its deprecated, and save you a headache later down the road when you're trying to update your code or refactoring.

Comment: What you're trying to do is simply have the user login securely and not disclose your private information such as username/password.. Throw the term API out the window.

Comment: Actually, this is the login module. I edited the script a bit. But the thing about the API is, it needs the "api_user" and "api_password" to be passed, which are sensitive data that users must not see.

Comment: You need to store the sensitive data in a database on the server side. You would pull the data from the database using sql/php

Comment: @David, Must I create a DB for just the sensitive data? Cant I just hard code them in the php script?

Comment: Yeah you could hardcode it in php if you really want to `$api_password = "password";` But if you have multiple users you will want a database

Comment: @David, Thanks a bunch, can you suggest any tools where I can test hosting the php script to perform the api request.

Comment: download wampserver. It's a local host that you can use on your computer for testing until your are ready to launch. It comes with phpMyAdmin which is a great tool for managing your databases.

Answer (score 0):

[CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is the solution. You can use it to perform get/post requests.. add parameters to your requests and get response. Everything you need to deal with the APIs.